# When is the solution of a matrix inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

I was doing the exercise on matrices at the end of the book answers are written a few have "inconsistent" in answers. what does this means? please help!

Comment: I suppose it means there more equations than the rank of the matrix and some equations are incompatible with the others. Use row reduction to check that.

Comment: that means you end up with an equation of the form $0 = 1$ that no matter what values you assign to the variables, all the equations can never be satisfied. and example is $x + y = 1, x + y = 2$

Answer (score 2):

It means that you matrix equation $Ax=b$ has no solutions. If $A$ is $m\times n$, then your equation corresponds to $m$ linear equations in $n$ variables, and these equations are "inconsistent" in the sense that they cannot all be true at the same time.